# Diferencia entre block y div

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, framework7

Estoy usando [Framework7](https://v4.framework7.io/docs/grid.html) para hacer una aplicación híbrida.
AL montar la pantallas el framework usa `hmtl` y `css`. En este punto no tengo clara cual es la diferencia entre la etiqueta

`<block></block>`

y la etiqueta

`<div></div>`

Mi pregunta es:

¿Cual es la diferencia entre ambas etiquetas?
¿Cuando se debe usar `block`  y cuando se debe usar `div` ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Es `<block>` o `<Block>`?

Comment: es <block> .  Añado el link en la pregunta del framework

Comment: en la documentación aparece en mayúscula <Block> sin embargo en los ejemplos esta en minúscula  <block>

Comment: En el enlace que has compartido no veo `<block>` en minúscula y no encuentro documentación sobre esa etiqueta (si voy a la parte de React sí que veo `<Block>`). Si ese es el caso (y `<block>` en minúsculas no existe), por defecto los navegadores interpretan las etiquetas desconocidas como si fueran un contenedor genérico, en cuyo caso `<div>` y `<block>` serían equivalentes (más  o menos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semánticamente son iguales, la diferencia es en los estilos:

- `<div>` es la etiqueta HTML que representa un bloque de contenido genérico y no tiene estilo ninguno (aparte de ser un elemento de bloque que ocupará todo el ancho del contenedor).
- `<Block>` es un [componente de React](https://framework7.io/react/block.html) que representa un bloque de contenido y que añade algo de formato (especialmente espaciado para el texto que va dentro). Se le pueden pasar props para cambiar dicho formato.

Según la [documentación de Framework7](https://framework7.io/docs/block.html), parece `<Block>` es equivalente a tener un `<div>` con la clase "block":

```
<div class="block">
  <!-- contenido de bloque -->
</div>
```

En ese mismo enlace tienen un ejemplo donde puedes ver elementos con `<Block>` y sin `<block>` y como los que van dentro de un `<Block>` no van directamente pegados a los bordes del contenedor sino que hay una separación.

Sobre cuando usarlos es algo relativo, pero la idea es usar `<Block>` cuando quieras los estilos de Framework7, y usar `<div>` (u otro elemento de bloque de HTML) cuando quieras usar estilos propios (como se indica en el [ejemplo de la documentación](https://framework7.io/docs/block.html#examples)).